# How to make a tailed Student's T-Test with R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have two sample data which are independent from each other.
So I have to make a two-sample independent student's t-test with this data using R.

When I call this :

```
t.test(data1, data2, alternative = "less", paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95)
```

The output is this :

```
        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  data1 and data2
t = -1.8795, df = 1121.445, p-value = 0.03022
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
       -Inf -0.2707661
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 45.08116  47.26238
```

But I want to test whether data2 is greater than data1. This tests whether they are equal or not.

Although this test says that they are equal, hence testing data2 > data1 is meaningless, I would like to know just in case they were not equal, to find which one has a greater mean value.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the **alternative** parameter to

```
t.test(data1, data2, alternative = "greater", paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95)
```

Comment: Thanks ! so the output p-value of this, is the probability that data2 > data1 , right ?

Comment: Yes. The alternative hypothesis in this case is `alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0`. i.e. the mean estimate of data2 is greater than mean estimate of data1.

Comment: Thanks again ! I have one final question, what is the reason for this output : 

`95 percent confidence interval:
       -4.091665       Inf` ? What resulted in infinity ?